# Seaborn distplot() won't display frequency in the y-axis

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I am trying to display the weighted frequency in the y-axis of a `seaborn.distplot()` graph, but it keeps displaying the density (which is the default in `distplot()`)

I read the [documentation](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.distplot.html) and also many similar questions here in Stack.

The common answer is to set `norm_hist=False` and also to assign the weights in a bumpy array as in a standard histogram. However, it keeps showing the density and not the probability/frequency of each bin.

My code is

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 4))
plt.xlim(-0.145,0.145)
plt.axvline(0, color='grey')
data = df['col1']

x = np.random.normal(data.mean(), scale=data.std(), size=(100000))
normal_dist =sns.distplot(x, hist=False,color="red",label="Gaussian")

data_viz = sns.distplot(data,color="blue", bins=31,label="data", norm_hist=False)

# I also tried adding the weights inside the argument
#hist_kws={'weights': np.ones(len(data))/len(data)})

plt.legend(bbox_to_anchor=(1, 1), loc=1)
```

And I keep receiving this output:

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of what could be the problem here?

Thanks!

[EDIT]: The problem is that the y-axis is showing the `kde`values and not those from the weighted histogram. If I set `kde=False` then I can display the frequency in the y-axis. However, I still want to keep the `kde`, so I am not considering that option.

Answer (score 1):

Keeping the `kde` and the `frequency/count` in one y-axis in one plot will not work because they have different scales. So it might be better to create a plot with 2 axis with each showing the kde and histogram separately. 
From documentation  **norm_hist** `If True, the histogram height shows a density rather than a count. **This is implied if a KDE or fitted density is plotted**.`

`versusnja` in https://github.com/mwaskom/seaborn/issues/479 has a workaround:

```
# Plot hist without kde.
# Create another Y axis.
# Plot kde without hist on the second Y axis.
# Remove Y ticks from the second axis.

first_ax  = sns.distplot(data, kde=False)
second_ax = ax.twinx()
sns.distplot(data, ax=second_ax, kde=True, hist=False)
second_ax.set_yticks([])
```

If you need this just for visualization it should be good enough.

Comment: Thanks! However, this solution only gives me the histogram, because the KDE is on other scale. Seeing that github post, it looks like there is no possible way to force the axis to show the weighted bins count :/